# Definition of weak $L^p$ spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-lp-spaces

Today I came across the notation $L_\text{weak}$ and I don't know what exactly it means. I can only find the [weak Lp spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Weak_Lp)
, but here they don't use the same notation. Is this the same thing?

I'm also a little bit confused by the norm given in the article: $$\|f\|_{p,w}:=\sup_{t>0}t\left(\mu\left\{x \in S: \left|f(x)\right|>t\right\}\right)^\frac{1}{p},$$

it doesn't seem to fit in the context of the computations in which I need it. Are the any common estimates (except for the bound by the $L^p$ norm) I don't see yet?

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: Can you give more background on $L_{weak}$ ? Where did you come across it

Comment: In the paper read it is not defined, it is just used sometimes to show convergence of sequences, for example it says: From $\rho _n \righarrow \rho$ in $C(I,L^\s_weak(\Omega))$ and $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $L^2(I,W_0^{1,2}(\Omega))$ it follows that $\rho _n u_n \rightarrow$ weakly star in $L^\infty(0,T;L^\frac{2s}{s+1}(\Omega))$.

Comment: Sorry, I was too slow to edit, it should be: $\rho _n \rightarrow \rho$ in $C(I,L^s_{weak}(\Omega))$

Comment: I don't know how to prove your result but it seems like the correct context. The weak Lebesgue space is written $L^p_w = L^{p,w}=L^{p,\text{weak}}$ etc, and also $L^{p,\infty}$ because it coincides with the Lorenz space with those parameters

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I couldn't find it out yet but then I will try further

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X,\mu)$ and $(Y,V)$ be measure spaces,and let $T$ be an operator from $L^{p}(X,\mu)$ into the space of measurable functions from $Y$ to $C$.We say that $T$ is weak $(p,q),q<\infty,$ if
$$ v(\{y\in Y:|Tf(y)|>\lambda\}) \le (\dfrac{C||f||_{p}}{\lambda})^{q} $$

an operator $K$ is of weak type $(2,2)$ means
$$ v(\{y\in Y:|Kf(y)|>\lambda\}) \le (\dfrac{C||f||_{2}}{\lambda})^{2}$$
means $$\lambda v(\{y\in Y:|Kf(y)|>\lambda\})^{1/2} \le C||f||_{2}$$
so $$||Kf||_{L^{2},\infty} \le C||f||_{2}$$